# Creating a bridge table equivalent realm class?

Tags: database, database-design, realm, realm-list

I am designing a database which I am planning to implement on Android using Realm. I am still exploring and reading about using the library but I have one question that concerns me. Is it possible to implement a bridge table (see the diagram bellow) using Realm?

From what I read in the "Relationships" section in the docs [link](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships), I can use RealmList object to do many to many relationships. For example, for the "User_Activity" table. However, I an still unsure how to "convert" the database design into Realm class equivalent.

[image]

Comment: Can a user belong to multiple activities? Can an activity belong to multiple users?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce An Activity (e.g. Static, Running, Walking) can belong to more then one User. This is how I saw it in my head. The table Activity will store only 4 entries - Walking, Running, Cyclking and Static and those will be referenced in the UserActivity and associated with different users.

Comment: ah, and you also record these previous past user activities by date.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Correct! My plan is later on to sort the user activities by date and present them in a ListView on Android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String userId;

    private String password;

    @Index
    private String username;

    private String paGoal; // ?

    private long maxInactivityInterval;

    private RealmList<UserActivity> userActivities;

    private Activity currentActivity; // optional
}

public class UserActivity extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String userIdAndActivityIdAndDate; // userid_activityid_2017-01-23

    @Index
    private Date date;

    private long duration;

    private User user;

    @Index
    private String userId;

    private Activity activity;

    @Index
    private String activityId;
}

public class Activity extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String activityId;

    @Index
    private String type;
}
```

I think this schema would work fine for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks very good. One question, though. The field "userIdAndActivityIdAndDate" will be a "compaund key" for example, if I have a user with userId = 1 and activity with activityId = 1 then the key will be looking like that -> 112017-01-23 is that correct?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev yup, exactly (although I prefer to separate them with `_`s) ~ also if you need hour/minute in your primary key, that's also something you should imagine there, so like `2017-01-23-18-00-00` or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define your classes like:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    ...
    private UserActivity userActivity;
}

public class UserActivity {
   private int id;
   private Activity activity;
}
```

You don't have to store the "foreign ID" in your model. Realm is actually storing the related linked objects as pointers underneath. So just follow the Realm's link [doc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships) and define the linked object as the field

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think what confused me was I was trying to design the database using the knowledge of typical databases and forgot that Realm is very object oriented almost like a typical class.

Comment: My main concern what how I will be able to associate a specific user with a specific activity. Do you think creating a RealmList< UserActivity> field in the User class will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

User_Activity table is a secondary table in database. Secondary tables help to bind related records from 2 different tables with many-to-many relationship. So, i see no reasons to define UserActivity class in Realm.

```
public class User {
   private RealmList<Activity> activities;
}

public class Activity {
   private RealmList<Users> users;
}
```

Should be enough if you want many-to-many relationship.

But as for your question, i believe you need one-to-many relationship, like that [image]

So, the correct definition would be something like following:

```
public class User {
   private RealmList<Activity> activities;
}

public class Activity {
   private user = User;
}
```

Comment: linking objects aren't supported in realm-java yet https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

Comment: I am really considering going with your approach (it is very simple) - having 2 tables - User with userId (and the other fields mentioned above and a RealmList of Activities) and Activity table with "type", "date" and "duration" fields (no id since I am planning to get the activities via the user's id).

Comment: Thanks. Thought, that was swift :)